# Password Regular expression with four criteria

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression in PHP to ensure a password matches a criteria which is:

- It should atleast 8 characters long
- It should include at least one special character
- It should include at least one capital letter.

I have written the following expression:

```
$pattern=([a-zA-Z\W+0-9]{8,})
```

However, it doesn't seem to work as per the listed criteria. Could I get another pair of eyes to aid me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex - `([a-zA-Z\W+0-9]{8,})` - actually searches for a substring in a larger text that is at least 8 characters long, but also allowing any English letters, non-word characters (other than `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`), and digits, so it **does not enforce 2 of your requirements**. They can be set with [*look-aheads*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

Here is a fixed regex:

```
^(?=.*\W.*)(?=.*[A-Z].*).{8,}$
```

Actually, you can replace `[A-Z]` with `\p{Lu}` if you want to also match/allow non-English letters. You can also consider using `\p{S}` instead of `\W`, or further precise your criterion of a `special character` by adding symbols or character classes, e.g. `[\p{P}\p{S}]` (this will also include all Unicode punctuation).

An enhanced regex version:

```
^(?=.*[\p{S}\p{P}].*)(?=.*\p{Lu}.*).{8,}$
```

**A human-readable explanation**:

- `^` - Beginning of a string
- `(?=.*\W.*)` - Requirement to have at least 1 non-word character

   **OR** `(?=.*[\p{S}\p{P}].*)` - At least 1 Unicode special or punctuation symbol
- `(?=.*[A-Z].*)` - Requirement to have at least 1 uppercase English letter

   **OR** `(?=.*\p{Lu}.*)` - At least 1 Unicode letter
- `.{8,}` - Requirement to have *at least* 8 symbols
- `$` - End of string

See [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/tE9oF3/4) and [Demo 2 (Enhanced regex)](https://regex101.com/r/tE9oF3/3)

Sample code:

```
if (preg_match('/^(?=.*\W.*)(?=.*[A-Z].*).{8,}$/u', $header)) {
 // PASS
} 
else {
    # FAIL
}
```

Comment: I think the OP said "at least 8 characters long", not exactly 8 characters long.

Comment: Normally, passwords don't contain spaces, but the OP wasn't specific about it and there's no rule about this.

Answer (score 2):

Using positive [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `?=` we make sure that all password requirements are met.

---

## Requirements for strong password:

At least 8 chars long
At least 1 Capital Letter
At least 1 Special Character

---

## Regex:

```
^((?=[\S]{8})(?:.*)(?=[A-Z]{1})(?:.*)(?=[\p{S}])(?:.*))$
```

---

## PHP implementation:

```
if (preg_match('/^((?=[\S]{8})(?:.*)(?=[A-Z]{1})(?:.*)(?=[\p{S}])(?:.*))$/u', $password)) {
    # Strong Password
} else {
    # Weak Password
}
```

---

## Examples:

```
12345678 - WEAK
1234%fff - WEAK
1234_44A - WEAK
133333A$ - STRONG
```

---

## Regex Explanation:

```
^ assert position at start of the string
1st Capturing group ((?=[\S]{8})(?:.*)(?=[A-Z]{1})(?:.*)(?=[\p{S}])(?:.*))
    (?=[\S]{8}) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
        [\S]{8} match a single character present in the list below
            Quantifier: {8} Exactly 8 times
            \S match any kind of visible character [\P{Z}\H\V]
    (?:.*) Non-capturing group
        .* matches any character (except newline) [unicode]
            Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    (?=[A-Z]{1}) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
        [A-Z]{1} match a single character present in the list below
            Quantifier: {1} Exactly 1 time (meaningless quantifier)
            A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
    (?:.*) Non-capturing group
        .* matches any character (except newline) [unicode]
            Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    (?=[\p{S}]) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
        [\p{S}] match a single character present in the list below
            \p{S} matches math symbols, currency signs, dingbats, box-drawing characters, etc
    (?:.*) Non-capturing group
        .* matches any character (except newline) [unicode]
            Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
$ assert position at end of the string
u modifier: unicode: Pattern strings are treated as UTF-16. Also causes escape sequences to match unicode characters
```

---

## Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/hE2dD2/1